# Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Tags: php, laravel, php-8

How to resolve this issues:  Trying to access array offset on value of type int?

PHP8

```
    public function processPayment(Request $request)
{      
     $orders = $request->get('order');
     $ordersArray = [];

     // getting orders details
     foreach($orders as $order)
     {
         if($order['id'])
         {
             $ordersArray[$order['id']]['order_id'] = $order['id'];
             $ordersArray[$order['id']]['quantity'] = $order['quantity'];

         }
         ddd($ordersArray);
     }
```

Comment: You can view this answer that can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/70505377/5661396

Comment: On which line?..

Comment: You should provide us information about where the error occurs

Comment: Asker should provide information about where the error occurs

Comment: geertjanknapen the errors occurs in this line:    
$ordersArray[$order['id']]['order_id'] = $order['id'];
 $ordersArray[$order['id']]['quantity'] = $order['quantity'];

Comment: $orders is not an array?

Comment: can you show what `dd($orders)` shows

Comment: Yes using var_dump:

This is the result:
array(4) {
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "Ut soluta alias porro."
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(2)
    ["sale_price"]=>
    int(399)
    ["total"]=>
    int(798)
  }
  [2]=>

Comment: this is the dd($order, $ordersArray); code: ^ array:5 [
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "Ut soluta alias porro."
  "quantity" => 2
  "sale_price" => 399
  "total" => 798
]
^ array:1 [
  1 => array:2 [
    "order_id" => 1
    "quantity" => 2
  ]
]

Answer (score 4):

I resolved my own problem using in this way: `if(isset($order['id']))`
before I did in this way:`if($order['id'])`

Comment: `!empty($order['id'])` will do both in one go.